# What does 'last' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

It may sound like a silly question, but here's a sentence

> The unusual deal began **last** February. Amidst breaking news about Yanukovich, the former Ukrainian president, fleeing Ukraine, a clipped, mechanical sound from his mobile phone alerted an OCCRP reporter to a new message.

(from [here](https://www.occrp.org/index.php/en/ccwatch/cc-watch-indepth/2505-moldova-criminal-underground-feeds-ukrainian-civil-war-with-russian-weapons))

The interesting part is that the text is published in July 2014. How come February 2014 is "last" from the standpoint of July 2014? Shouldn't it be called "this" February whereas "last" February would've meant February 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• [Collins Dictionary says](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/last) "You use **last** in expressions such as ***last*** Friday, ***last*** night, and ***last*** year to refer, for example, to the *most recent* Friday, night, or year."
• [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Online says](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/last) "**Last** is most *recent or nearest* to the present time".

This means "last February" is not "last year's February", "last February" is "the most recent February", and in July 2014 the most recent February was February 2014.

As for ***this*** February, [Collins dictionary says (meaning 8)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/this) "You use **this** to refer to the *next* occurrence in the future of a particular day, month, season, or festival."

> We're getting married this June.

It means that from the standpoint of June 2014 "this February" would mean February 2015.
[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Online puts it](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/this) a bit differently: "**This** is used to talk about the *present time* or a time that is *close to the present*" which means that "this February" would mean "February 2014" since it is the closest February to June 2014.
Anyway, "last February" is February 2014.

Comment: What is "last year" here: https://ibb.co/nn1WR6q

Answer (score 1):

We use **last** (as in *last year*) when we refer to things that happened previously and recently (not long ago). Whereas we use **this** (as in *this year*) when we talk about a time period which is still going on. Consider these:

> I went to Miami last year. (= I went to Miami the very previous year)
>
> I went to Miami this year. (= I went to Miami this year [the year which is still going on])

In other words, “**this**” can be used to mean something which is going to happen in the near future (when the future tense and the present tense are involved) or has already happened [when the past tense is involved] in the time period which is still going on. Consider this:

> I am going to the church this week. (= I haven’t gone to the church yet but I will this week)